# Create dynamic URL using primary key in django

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm developing a website, it creates url for every article using slug (entered manually by the admin who is posting the article)
However I'm trying to change it to be dynamically generated using pk. Note that there is no content uploaded in the website so it won't affected by this change. Here is the current code and my main problem is that I don't know how to change it to pk. and when I try the available solutions I don't know where it should be passed through HTML pages.

```py
#view.py
def DetailView(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post})
```

```
#models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/')
    content = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True)
    post_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices= categories_list, default='0')


    #To order posts based on created dates decsend 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
#urls.py

path('<slug:slug>/', views.DetailView, name='post_detail'),
```

and here is how it's being passed to the html

```
<p><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{post.content|safe |slice:":10" }}</a></p>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change your `urls.py` to

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView, name='post_detail'),
```

Update your `DetailView` to

```
def DetailView(request, pk):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post})
```

Update your html `<p>` tag to to

```
<p><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk  %}">{{post.content|safe |slice:":10" }}</a></p>
```

Comment: Did this help you solve the issue?